# Alternative API to Google Maps for displaying lines and shape

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I am looking for an alternative for using Google Maps in my android application. I want my app to guide a person around routes, not roads or paths but following others tracks, and I think this will contradict the Google Maps T&C which states it can't be used for navigation.

Anyway I am mainly using the maps to display lines and shapes, as well as the positions of other users, in fact the maps are merely used as background.

Would anyone know of a good alternative which could be used in a commercial product. A mapping api would be ideal although I have even thought about plotting the lines and shapes on a canvas (I'm converting GPS coords to utm myself so this is not a problem), but I don't know if this would work??

Thanks for the help
Gareth

Answer (score 0):

You can use osmdroid. From [the documentation](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid):

> osmdroid is a (almost) full/free replacement for Android's MapView (v1 API) class. It also includes a modular tile provider system with support for numerous online and offline tile sources and overlay support with built-in overlays for plotting icons, tracking location, and drawing shapes.

You can use it in your project adding the dependencies:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.5:release@aar'
}
```